# Getting a neon light on the handset of an old GPO 700 series telephone to illuminate

Tags: neon

I have been given an old handset for a 700 SRS rotary GPO telephone, with a neon light in the centre.

If it is connected across the ringer circuit, should it light up when the bell set is energised by the 90VAC, or is the voltage too low requiring additional equipment within the phone to raise the voltage?

I'm assuming that neon lights are not polarity sensitive either given that it is an AC device.

Comment: From memory, the neon should work at about 60 V. When used on mains they are usually fitted with a series resistor which will limit the current. The Wikipedia article was useful last time I looked.

Comment: The trigger voltage is higher but so it is the peak voltage of the 200V ringer. yes it should light up

Comment: shine a light on the neon lamp ... it may start to work ... i have noticed the behavior in illuminated power switches on power bars ... the switch illuminates only when the room lights are on

Answer (score 2):

This is the [handset no. 7](https://www.britishtelephones.com/hands7.htm).

> In the ideal arrangement the lamp is powered from the ringing current
> on the line and flashes until the call is either answered or
> abandoned. Such an arrangement can be achieved if automatic ringing is
> derived from a 75-volt ringing generator and the lamp is connected
> directly in series with the bell.
>
> As shown in Diagram N 1901 a resistor is connected in parallel with
> the lamp to extend its life by limiting the current flow

In those days of course the bell would be 2 x 500 ohm; for modern use there should be a 3k3 resistor in series with it to convert it to high impedance parallel connection.

The [Diagram N1901](http://www.samhallas.co.uk/repository/n_diagrams/1000/N1901.pdf) is available from Sam Hallas' website.

Answer (score 1):

A neon should strike at about 80V.  So if your 90V AC really is 90V, then it should work.

Neons can fail with age, often becoming blackened over time, so you can't see the glow even if it's there.

Answer (score 0):

Neon lights are polarity sensitive as DC will glow only one terminal side but -48 is not enough to trigger that but 200Vpp (AFAIR) ring voltage is more than enough and even 60Vrms( I seem to recall current limiting with 100k to 120V rms as this is a negative resistance arc, the voltage drops when triggered.)